# letsencrypt standalone certification not showing up on GET request

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt

I was able to create certifications under the path `/etc/letsencrypt/{{mywebdomain}}/` and set under my server where the `ssl_cert` and `ssl_cert_key` absolute pathfile locations for my nginx server.

When I run the command `sudo nginx -t` I receive a successful configuration output and the nginx server is running in the reverse proxy for Django without any problems. But when I access the root of my website on my chrome browser, I'm receiving the "http://website.com" instead of "https://website.com".

Please point me in the right direction if anyone was able to correctly encrypt their domain content with gunicorn-django-nginx configuration.

My website snippet conf:

```
upstream app_server {
    unix:/home/me/Documents/masterdomain/src/portfolio_revamp.sock;
}

 server {
    client_max_body_size 4M;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen www.mysite.com:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
                http://example.com;

    ssl_certificate 
             /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key 
            /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;

    root /home/akeem/Documents/SpencerMaster/src;

    index templates/home.html templates/main.html;

    location / {
            proxy_pass
  http://unix:/home/me/Documents/masterdomain/src/portfolio_revamp.sock;
            alias /home/me/Documents/master/templates/home.html;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

    location /static {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/me/Documents/masterdomain/static;
    }

    location /media {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/me/Documents/masterdomain/media;
    }

  }
```

I'm running a xenial ubuntu 16.04 server if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you aren't redirecting to HTTPS - unless you specifically enter https://example.com, you'll be directed to the standard http://example.com.

I use [this guide from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-5-enabling-the-changes-in-nginx) which recommends two server blocks. In your case it will look something like:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    client_max_body_size 4M;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    No server_name required here

    ... Everything else ...
}
```